# C++ template name binding in gcc-6.3.0

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, argument-dependent-lookup

I learn the C++ template name binding and instantiation recently, and find the strange behavious in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int f(T a)
{
    return g(a); // g() should be dependent name
}

struct C {};
int g(C c)
{
    return 0;
}

int g(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    // Works!
    int z = f(C{});

    // Error: no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation
    //int z = f(10);

    cout << z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think `g(T)` should be dependent name and `int z = f(10)` should work like `int z = f(C{})`. But **gcc-6.3.0** complains:

```
g++ -g -o tmpl tmpl.cpp
tmpl.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int f(T) [with T = int]’:
tmpl.cpp:29:17:   required from here
tmpl.cpp:8:13: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
     return g(a);
            ~^~~
tmpl.cpp:18:5: note: ‘int g(int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
 int g(int i)
```

Comment: It works if declare `g(int)` before template. However, it still works if `g(C)` **NOT** declare before template.

Comment: This is due to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). When `g` is called with a parameter of type `C` there will be an extra function name lookup in the same scope as `C` is declared.

Comment: @super: That looks like an answer, although it would benefit from a bit more explanation. Please don't answer in comments, as sfz cannot select a comment as the correct answer.